How can I filter out empty queues in MSMQ using PHP?
`Hello,
I am currently working on a server-side PHP application that interacts with Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ) using COM objects. My goal is to filter out empty queues when processing messages. Here is some context about my setup and what I've tried so far:
I am working with a local host PC queue system.
My queue is named .\private$\messages.
I am using PHP to interact with MSMQ.
I want to implement a way to check if the queue is empty before attempting to process messages. In the current implementation, I use PeekCurrent() to check if there is a message in the queue, but I am looking for a more efficient or standard way to filter out empty queues.

Is there a more efficient method to check if an MSMQ queue is empty in PHP?
Are there any best practices or common patterns for handling empty queues in MSMQ?
How can I improve my current approach to ensure that I am correctly identifying and handling empty queues?`

